# Can two Riemannian manifolds (dim≠4) be homeomorphic without being bi-Lipschitz homeomorphic?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry

Topological manifolds of dimension ≠4 have a [Lipschitz structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#Lipschitz_manifolds). [Ed: Is this "well-known"? Is it obvious? Can somebody give a reference?] Does this imply the following result?

> Assume M and N are smooth Riemannian manifold, with same dimension other than 4. If M homeomorphic to N, then M is bi-Lipschitz homeomorphic to N.

In other words, can two manifolds (of dimension ≠4) be homeomorphic without being [bi-Lipschitz homeomorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#Lipschitz_manifolds)?

Comment: Is it a question or a statement?

Comment: Whatever it is, it doesn't seem to be at.algebraic-topology.

Comment: This question needs massive improvement.  Complete sentences and correct capitalization would help; glossing the terms would also be appropriate; motivation and background, here on MO, is generally a must-have.

Comment: It's not *that* bad, Theo, surely? My reading of it is as a question about whether two (Riemannian) smooth manifolds of dimension $\ne 4$ can be homeomorphic without being bi-Lipshitz holomorphic.

Comment: ... and the first comment is claiming (I don't know if this claim is correct) that a topological manifold of finite dimension other than 4 can be equipped with a metric such that the induced topology is equivalent to the given one

Comment: Typo above: "holomorphic" should be "homeomorphic" obviously...

Comment: I'm with Theo on this one. MetricGeometry, please clean this up - there's an interesting question here but it's buried. First, we have to overlook the absence of grammar, punctuation and capitalization, and we're expected to know that "Lip" means Lipschitz. Next, your question is probably not "Does A imply B?" but "Is B true?" Then it's not clear (to me) how a smooth structure and Riemannian metric is relevant if the question is (as I think) about Lipschitz structures. Finally, the question in the title seems to be different from the one in the text.

Comment: Yes, but probably you should spell it with the "c" ;-)

Comment: With Anton's edits, I've removed my -1.  I'm not a differential geometer, although if I were on television I think I'd like to play one.  But anyway, I do read MO in large part to learn some math by reading other people's questions.  I had no idea what "Lip" means, although without looking it up I have some idea for "Libschitz", for example.  In any case, I'd still love to see some more motivation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't assume compactness, then no. Silly example: $\mathbb R^1$ and $(0,1)$. Example with complete metrics: $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb H^2$ (they have essentially different volume growths and hence are not bi-Lipschitz equivalent).

If $M$ and $N$ are closed, then yes, by Sullivan's uniqueness result pointed out to by Leonid Kovalev in comments (provided that the MR review is correct - I'm not an expert in any way and don't have access to the paper). The uniqueness means that for every two Lipschitz structures there is an isomorphism between them. And for Lipschitz structures  defined by Riemannian metrics, isomorphisms are a locally bi-Lipschitz homeomorphisms of the metrics. By compactness, locally bi-Lipschitz implies bi-Lipschitz.

Comment: Sullivan's paper is somewhat hard to read, but its results are reproved and generalized in [Luukkainen, Lipschitz and quasiconformal approximation of homeomorphism pairs. Topology Appl. 109 (2001), no. 1, 1--40]. 

Comment: @Leonid: Actually it was "bi-Lip" in the question and who knows what it meant to the OP. I've made the answer community wiki, you are welcome to replace my excuses by precise information.
